# Owner on CentOS changes to a numeric value after a set time

Tags: centos, user-permissions, windows-authentication

I have a CentOS web server that uses Windows Authentication from a 2012 r2 server on the network.

Here is my issue:

When I log on, all directories ls -l shows:

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jbailey@domainname.com apache   17 Sep 25 14:46 jbworkarea
```

After a set time, about 3-5 minutes, all permissions for my username change to a number:

example (same directory):

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x.  3 1869806575 apache   17 Sep 25 14:46 jbworkarea
```

At that point all SCP file system (WinSCP...) connections report that I do not have privileges.
To restore, (even though my username is in sudoers, I do not need to be sudo) to just:

```
chown "jbailey@domainname.com" .
```

Then all privs report fine with ls -l and with WinSCP... For the next few minutes.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Here is #realm list

```
    mydomain.com 
type: kerberos 
realm-name: MYDOMAIN.COM 
domain-name: MYDOMAIN.com 
configured: kerberos-member 
server-software: active-directory 
client-software: sssd 
required-package: oddjob 
required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir 
required-package: sssd 
required-package: adcli 
required-package: samba-common-tools 
login-formats: %U@MYDOMAIN.com 
login-policy: allow-permitted-logins 
permitted-logins: myname@mydomain.com, ... , ... permitted-groups
```

Comment: In order to diagnose the issue, we need to know the exact mechanism/software you are using for authentication.

Comment: Using Windows Server 2012r2 as a Domain Controller w/ Active Directory Authentication

Comment: And how is CentOS configured to use that authentication? What is the software stack, how is it configured?

Comment: Please add the configuration into the question so that it can be easily read.

Comment: So linux server permissions are off topic?

Answer (score 0):

The band-aid for now is to run a cron job every 2 minutes, running `chown` (which is obviously updating some tables somewhere)

```
*/2 * * * * chown "jbailey@mydomain.com" /home/jbailey@mudomain.com
```